# @Value failing in Spring MVC 3.0.6

Tags: java, spring-mvc, annotations

I have create a Service and loading it using @Service("amazonService").
My application context is loading this service using  
 I am configuring the properties using

```
<bean id="propsHolder"
    class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="ignoreResourceNotFound" value="true" />
    <property name="locations">
        <list>
            <value>classpath:/applicationConfig.properties</value>

        </list>
    </property>

</bean>
```

In my Amazon service i do:

```
    public class AmazonServiceImpl implements FileStorageService {

    private AmazonS3 amazonClient;
    @Value("${abcxyz}")
    public String bucketName ;
```

And my props file has a property abcxyz = my-bucket

But this fails badly with the following exception:

```
 Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: public java.lang.String com.flipswap.service.impl.AmazonServiceImpl.bucketName; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No matching bean of type [java.lang.String] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value(value=${abczyz})}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:508)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:84)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:285)
    ... 50 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No matching bean of type [java.lang.String] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value(value=${abczyz})}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoSuchBeanDefinitionException(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:924)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:793)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:707)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:480)
    ... 52 more


Everyone is able to do this successfully and even i succeeded it in a plain java sample. But running in MVC fails.

Any idea?
```

Comment: Wierd thing is that i dont know y it is trying to autowire @Value placeholder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it! Actually the App had configured its custom XMLWebapplication context in web.xml as its spring context loader listener.

This was not passing in the call to the super method which was actually responsible for registering @Value annotation processors.

Answer (score 0):

This is strange. Even if the property is somehow not loaded, the `@Value` annotation should resolve to the string inside the brackets.

So try upgrading to 3.1 (which was recently released), or downgrade to 3.0.5 (where I'm sure this worked). Also make sure you haven't changed the default autowiring strategy in your xml.

Answer (score 0):

```
<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:/applicationConfig.properties"/>
```

instead.

---

Please make sure that the Spring Configuration file is really loaded: add some syntax error in it, if the application run like before, then the problem is that the file is not used like expected.

Comment: @hellojava: please check the application at all (see the hint in my answer)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer bean is declared in the same application context as your controller.  BeanFactoryPostProcessors such as PPC are not inherited across parent/child application context boundaries.  It may be that your PPC is declared in your 'root' application context, but your component-scanning directive is declared in the child (dispatcher servlet) context.  This won't work, and would render the results you've reported.